# Aggregate daily data to calculate monthly average

Tags: python

Hello I am a new user to Python and I am having problem doing what I imagined was a fairly basic task.

I have several (>50) csv files containing daily snow depth data.  I would like to iterate through the csv files and calculate monthly means for the snow depth.  Data example:

```
Date,SD
1/1/2000,36
1/2/2000,36
1/3/2000,38
1/4/2000,40
2/1/2000,48
2/2/2000,48
```

In other words I would like to calculate monthly snow depth averages and write the output to a new csv file.  I was able to modify a different example of code for my data, but I am receiving Key Errors for using Date as the key value in my Dictionary.

Any advice?

Code so far:

```
from __future__ import division
import csv
from collections  import defaultdict

def default_factory():
    return [0, None, None, 0]

reader = csv.DictReader(open(r'C:\SandBox\VALIDATION\TestTable.csv'))

dates = defaultdict(default_factory)
for row in reader:
    sd = int(row["SD"])
    dates[row["Dates"]][0] += sd
    max = dates[row["Dates"]][1]
    dates[row["Dates"]][1] = amount if max is None else amount if amount > max else max
    min = dates[row["Date"]][2]
    dates[row["Dates"]][2] = amount if min is None else amount if amount < min else min
    dates[row["Dates"]][3] += 1

for date in dates:
    dates[date][3] = dates[date][0]/dates[date][3]

writer = csv.writer(open(r'C:\SandBox\VALIDATION\TestAvg.csv', 'w', newline = ''))
writer.writerow(["Date", "SD", "max", "min", "mean"])
writer.writerows([date] + dates[date] for date in dates)
```

EDIT: Just to clarify, I am trying to achieve total monthly mean, i.e. January mean, February mean, etc... not calculate a mean for a single date.

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace/error?

Comment: If you are calculating mean and not median, why do you care about min and max?

Comment: As WolframH said your csv has the first line of "Date,Snowdepth" but your code is looking for "Dates,SD"

Comment: jgritty, that is just a relic of some code I used as a reference. Doesn't really matter if it is in the output or not.

Comment: For jgritty:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SandBox\Scripting\snotel.py", line 17, in <module>
    dates[row["Dates"]][0] += sd
KeyError: ('Dates',)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use a dictionary to make the code a little more readable.

```
from __future__ import division
import csv
from collections  import defaultdict

def default_factory():
   return { "sum": 0, "max": None, "min": None, "count": 0}

reader = csv.DictReader(open(r'sd.csv'))

dates = defaultdict(default_factory)
rows = []
for row in reader:
    date = row["Date"]
    sd = int(row["Snowdepth"])
    rows.append([date, sd])
    month = date.split("/")[0]
    r = dates[month]
    r["sum"] += sd
    max = r["max"]
    r["max"] = sd if max is None else sd if sd > max else max
    min = r["min"]
    r["min"] = sd if min is None else sd if sd < min else min
    r["count"] += 1

for date in dates:
    r = dates[date]
    r["avg"] = r["sum"]/r["count"]

writer = csv.writer(open(r'TestAvg.csv', 'w'))
writer.writerow(["Date", "SD", "max", "min", "mean"])
for row in rows:
    r = dates[row[0].split("/")[0]]
    writer.writerow(row + [r["max"], r["min"], r["avg"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Someplaces you have used `Dates` as column name (e.g. `max = dates[row["Dates"]][1]`), and other place it is `Date` (e.g. `min = dates[row["Date"]][2]`), from you example of data looks like `Date` is the column name? so if you use same name everywhere it should be ok eg.

```
s="""Date,Snowdepth
1/1/2000,36
1/2/2000,36
1/3/2000,38
1/4/2000,40
2/1/2000,48
2/2/2000,48"""

import StringIO
import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO.StringIO(s))

for row in reader:
    print row['Date']
```

output:

```
1/1/2000
1/2/2000
1/3/2000
1/4/2000
2/1/2000
2/2/2000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import division
import csv
from collections  import defaultdict

def default_factory():
    return [0, None, None, 0]

reader = csv.DictReader(open(r'snow_data.csv'))

dates = defaultdict(default_factory)

for row in reader:
    amount = int(row["Snowdepth"])
    dates[row["Date"]][0] += amount
    max = dates[row["Date"]][1]
    dates[row["Date"]][1] = amount if max is None else amount if amount > max else max
    min = dates[row["Date"]][2]
    dates[row["Date"]][2] = amount if min is None else amoun if amount < min else min
    dates[row["Date"]][3] += 1


for date in dates:
    dates[date][3] = dates[date][0]/dates[date][3]

writer = csv.writer(open(r'TestAvg.csv', 'w'))
writer.writerow(["Date", "Snowdepth", "max", "min", "mean"])
writer.writerows([date] + dates[date] for date in dates)
```

I fixed the code to use `Date` and `Snowdepth` everywhere as, that is what your sample csv provides.  Also, you had a variable `amount` which was intended to be `sd` otherwise amount is not defined.  I made that one `amount` everywhere.

It won't give very exciting results unless you have multiple entries for a single date.

For example, here is the output from your sample csv:

```
Date,Snowdepth,max,min,mean

1/3/2000,38,38,38,38.0

2/2/2000,48,48,48,48.0

2/1/2000,48,48,48,48.0

1/4/2000,40,40,40,40.0

1/1/2000,36,36,36,36.0

1/2/2000,36,36,36,36.0
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.  I would like to achieve monthly average (i.e. January mean of 36.6667) not daily average.